# I need to round the number of a field

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have tried many things about the rounding of a filed but I get NaN, here is what I am trying to round up to 999999,9

document.forms[0].NB_CONCN_MOY_DCO_MS

I have tried Math.round(document.forms[0].NB_CONCN_MOY_DCO_MS.value)

and

document.forms[0].Math.round(NB_CONCN_MOY_DCO_MS.value)

what can I do now.

Comment: Is this HTML and JavaScript? (What is the c99 tag you put on here for?)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to round a number to one decimal place in JavaScript, use `someNumber.toFixed(1)`. Note that the `value` of form fields is a string (not a number) so you'll want to convert it to a number first.

```
var n = document.forms[0].NB_CONCN_MOY_DCO_MS.value * 1;
var rounded = n.toFixed(1);
```

If your value has commas in it to represent decimal values, you will need to fix the string to use periods instead first:

```
var n = document.forms[0].NB_CONCN_MOY_DCO_MS.value.replace(/,/,',') * 1;
var rounded = n.toFixed(1);
```

Comment: +1.  You could also use `Number.prototype.toFixed.call(document.forms[0].NB_CONCN_MOY_DCO_MS.value, 1)`, which would automatically coerce to a number.